# VAST 2.0 + googledrive

Tags: node.js, iframe, google-drive-api, vast

What is the correct way to use VAST on iframe embeds? I'm unable to find any documentation for doing so. Which leads me to believe either it requires a back-end call/function, or its simply not possible?

My goal.

Googledrive Embed (iframe) - Hook VAST code to that embeded player for pre-roll before media.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use VAST with a player, this particular player

a) needs to support VAST and 
b) you need to have control over the player.

Imao, the Google Drive Embed Player is the YouTube Player which brings us to

a) afaik, no API for VAST support and
b) everything which controls the player is embedded too - meaning, it's very hard to do something here.

Conclusion:
Afiag not possible but if you could live without the directly embedded player, you might be able to use the Google Drive Embed Player as source.

Comment: I could setup a script to curl my drive links into mp4 url's, and then use something like flow player, or even chrome's native html5. Which then I have 100% control of player source.

But that would be time consuming, even if automated. (automating it server side becomes a CPU killer)

Which brings me back to my original question. Is there any documentation I can read about writing a JS environment to hook the iframe embed code of existing content? 

I know you can display VAST over html page. So even if it was just before the player embed loads, that'd be fine.